# OCaml find number of times n is present in list

Tags: list, ocaml

I am a beginner with OCmal. I have a list named `l` and a number stored in `N`.
I need to find the number of times `N` repeats in `l`.

```
let l = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;1;9;10;11];;
let n = 1;;
```

I want to write a function which tells that number of times `n` is present in `l`.

I started like this but I am blocked:

```
for i = 0 to (List.length l) do
(* codes here: i want to find that the value of N is present twice in the list *)
done;;
```

Comment: You're starting with a loop, which is an imperative style solution. I would recommend that you imagine solving the problem with a recursive function. That will lead you toward a functional solution, which is usually the point of studying OCaml.

Answer (score 0):

(*Declaration of the list l*)

let l = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;1;9;10;11];;

(*Declaration of the constant n to 1*)

let n = 1;;

(*Declaration of the variable (counter) initialized to 0*)

let counter = ref 0;;

(*Declaration of the recursive function (occ) taking a list and an int as parameters*)

let rec occ l n =
  match l with

(*If the current list is empty, it prints n and its occurences*)

[] -> Printf.printf "The number of occurences of %d in the list is : %d\n" n !counter

(*If the current list is not empty, in other words, having a head (h) and a tail (t) that is by the way a potential end of the list : if h=n it increments the counter by 1, and re-calls the occ function with the rest of the list, which is (t), else, it re-calls (occ) with (t) without incrementing the counter*)

|h::t -> if h = n then (incr counter; occ t n) else occ t n;;

(*Test*)

occ l n;;

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list and after that enumerate elements of it with calculating the repetition count for each number. This algorithm will have O (n*log(n)).

```ml
let of_times n l = 
  match List.sort Int.compare l with
  | []     -> []
  | h :: t -> 
      let rec f current count = function
        | h :: t when h = current -> f h (succ count) t
        | h :: t when n = count   -> current :: (f h 1 t)
        | h :: t                  -> f h 1 t
        | []                      -> [] in
      f h 1 t
```

Better O is possible only with the mutable state using. In the current case, it will be hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `List.fold`?

```
List.fold_left(fun acc x -> if x = N then acc + 1 else acc)0 l
```